# Javascript boolean if statement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to animate a panel to come in and out from the top of the page. Unfortunately my if statement is not working. Here's my code:

```
var panelShown = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav_arrow').click(function(){
        panelShown = true;
        $('#nav_panel').animate({top: '0px'}, 1000, function(){});
        $('#nav_bar');
    });
    if(panelShown == true){//originally written as if(panelShown){
        $(document).click(function(){
            panelShown = false;
            $('#nav_panel').animate({top: '-200px'}, 1000, function(){});
        });
    }
});
```

The first part works fine, the panel animates down. But I can never get into the if statement. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Damn, I'm an idiot. The if statement needs to be inside the click listener. :/

Comment: Stepping through your code (i.e. _debugging_) would have made this immediately apparent.

Comment: It looks like StackOverflow is now a hi-tech version of [Rubber Duck debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) ;-)

Comment: I'm using a notepad, I don't have much debugging. I tried using console.log, but I just missed that it was only running once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really whould never be called because on `ready` it will be `false`.

Try this:

```
var panelShown = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav_arrow').click(function(){  
        $('#nav_panel').animate({top: (panelShown ?'-200px' : '0px')}, 1000, function(){});
        panelShown = !panelShown;
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, just realised that there, thanks :) 9 minutes until I can accept your answer.